# Использование php совместно с node.js

Tags: node.js, php, сессия

Есть сайт на php с регистрацией и возможностью пользователям отсылать личные сообщения, такой тет-а-тет чат(как вконтакте). Было необходимо сделать этот чат на node.js + sockets.io. Чат, работает, но как мне вывести имена пользователей, которые залогинены, ведь node не понимает сессий php?

Answer (score 1):

Как варианта общаться get/post запросами на определенные пути.

Comment: А можно пример?
Так же, я пробовал делать так:
var parsedJSON = require('../test.php');
var user = JSON.parse(parsedJSON);
В test.php:
header('Content-Type:application/json');
echo json_encode($user); 
но, как я понял, сервер видит лишь голый код php